# How to activate the vscode main window via its API?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I write a lisp debugger for vscode, and I want to activate the vscode main window via its API.
Is there such an API for vscode?

Comment: "activate"? Do you mean give it focus?

Comment: Yes, I mean to bring the VSCODE window to the foreground window in Windows Explorer.